# errors in php paypal paying

Tags: php, paypal

**I choose the product, then click on the PayPal button, then enter the account, then click pay, and this error appears**

**error in image**

Does trying the code on a local server cause this error?

```
     paypal.Button.render({
        env: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalEnv; ?>',
        client: {
            sandbox: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>',
            production: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>'
        },
        locale: 'en_US',
        style: {
            size: 'small',
            color: 'gold',
            shape: 'pill',
        },
        commit: true,
        funding: {
            allowed: [paypal.FUNDING.CARD],
            disallowed: [paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT]
        },
        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [{
                    amount: {
                        total: '<?php echo $productData['price']; ?>',
                        currency: '<?php echo $productData['currency']; ?>'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onError: function (err) {
    alert(err);
    
    return;
  },
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute()
                .then(function() {
                    window.location = "process.php?paymentID=" + data.paymentID + "&token=" + data.paymentToken + "&payerID=" + data.payerID + "&pid=<?php echo $productData['id']; ?>";
                });
        }
    }, '#paypal-button');
```

Comment: error in this link    https://b.top4top.io/p_2031qwf9f1.png

Comment: URL apparently contains malware, also you are using an outdated 'checkout.js' integration.  The current one is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/